# Merge cells with same content in reports in Access

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to merge the cells in a column that contain the same content in Microsoft Access, as you do in Excel?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In design view of the report, go to properties of that field and set the property:

Hide Dupes: Yes

Comment: In this way "Monday" is shown in the first row and the others are blank. Can't I visually merge them in a "big" cell?

Comment: No. A row is a row with fields of equal height.

Comment: It is hard, but you can visually merge them, if you make border around Date's TextBox invisible, and then write function that will draw corresponding lines on `OnPrint` event of rows.